# DirectShowLib IMediaEventEx.GetEvent on 64-bit returning 0

Tags: vb.net, directshow, directshow.net

I fear this maybe an esoteric one but after some searching I'm wondering whether anyone else has encountered this problem?  The issue is that when calling IMediaEventEx.GetEvent method, the 'EventCode' parameter always returns 0 when running on a 64-bit machine.  The same code and similar environment but on a 32-bit machine works fine.

This method is being called within the familar 'HandleGraphEvent' method that is called by capturing the appropriate WM_GRAPHNOTIFY message.  More specifically I'm looking for the 'DirectShowLib.EventCode.Complete' message that is called when a video file has completed.  As mentioned, on 32-bit systems (that is working) it generates the event code / message 'ClockChanged', 'Paused' and finally the 'Complete' in that order.  On the 64-bit machine, the HandleGraphEvent method is called three times as well, but each time the GetEvent is called, the EventCode is 0.

Has anyone else experienced this problem or issues moving DirectShowLib code from 32-bit to 64-bit?

Thanks in advance...

FWIW - the code...

```
Private Sub HandleGraphEvent()
    ' This routine handles are notified events from DShow library
    Dim hr As Integer
    Dim evCode As EventCode
    Dim evParam1, evParam2 As Integer
    If Me.m_MediaEventEx Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    ' Process all the events
    While (Me.m_MediaEventEx.GetEvent(evCode, evParam1, evParam1, 0) = 0)
        ' Cleanup parameters before processing
        hr = Me.m_MediaEventEx.FreeEventParams(evCode, evParam1, evParam2)
        IsDShowError(hr, "HandleGraphEvent")

        ' Is this the end of the movie?
        If evCode = EventCode.Complete Then
            ' Is there a movie control availalbe?
            If Me.m_MediaControl Is Nothing Or Me.m_MediaSeek Is Nothing Then Return
            ' Perform Stop Start
            hr = Me.m_MediaControl.Stop()
            PlayMovie(MoveToNextVideo())
            Exit While
        End If
    End While
End Sub
```

Comment: Something you might want to also check is a typo in line `GetEvent(evCode, evParam1, evParam1`. You wanted third argument `evParam2` instead, didn't you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across a reference to DirectShow changing the implementation of some of the interfaces to use `IntPtr` in place of `Int` for 64-bit support :

> http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/
>
> We have also corrected problems related 64 bit support. Primarily fixing "pack" problems on structures, but a few interfaces have been changed to support 64 bit. Primarily changing parameters from int to IntPtr. This will require code changes where you are using them, but the changes are relatively obvious, and are easily located with a re-compile.

Indeed :

> [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd406907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
>
> ```
> HRESULT GetEvent(
>   [out]  long *lEventCode,
>   [out]  LONG_PTR *lParam1,
>   [out]  LONG_PTR *lParam2,
>   [in]   long msTimeout
> );
> ```

So perhaps :

```
Dim evParam1, evParam2 As IntPtr
```

Your `EventCode` type would also, I think, need to be passed as an IntPtr (unless this is its type already).  The `Integer` type remains a 32-bit number even when compiled for x64 (for the same reason that the `Short` type, etc, remains available to 32-bit applications).  Pointers for 64-bit applications, however, are all 64-bit quantities so passing a 32-bit `Integer` won't work.  The `IntPtr` structure is platform dependent - 32-bit for x86 and 64-bit for x64.

Comment: Excellent stuff, turns out I was not using the 2005 library that had the Intptr signatures.  Changing the library and data types worked a treat.  Thank you!